# How to integrate $\int_{2}^4 \frac{1+x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int_{2}^4 \frac{1+x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx $$
I am trying to integrate the above expression by writing the expression as $$\int_{2}^4 \frac{1}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx +\int_{2}^4 \frac{x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx $$
Now I can easily integrate
$$\int_{2}^4 \frac{x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx $$
To integrate this we have to substitute $x^{2}$ $=$ $u$. Now $x×dx$ $=$ $du/2$
Because, $1+2x^{2}+x^{4}$ can be written as $(x^{2}+1)^{2}$. But I am facing problem to integrate $$\int_{2}^4 \frac{1}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx $$
Please help me out to integrate.

Comment: Notice the denominator is $(x^2+1)^2=(x+i)^2(x-i)^2$. Now substitute $x=\tan(\theta)$ or use partial fractions.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate, without breaking up the integral, as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^4 \frac{1+x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx\\
=& \int_{2}^4 \frac1{2(x-1)}d\bigg[ \frac{(x-1)^2}{1+x^2}\bigg]\\
\overset{ibp}=&-\frac1{85}+\frac12\int_2^4\frac1{1+x^2}dx
=-\frac1{85}+\frac12\tan^{-1}\frac29
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^4 \frac{1+x}{1+2x^{2}+x^{4}}dx\\
\overset{x=\tan \theta}=& \int_{\arctan 2}^{\arctan 4} \frac{1+\tan\theta}{\sec^4\theta}\sec^2\theta d\theta\\
=&\int_{\arctan 2}^{\arctan 4} (\cos^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta)d\theta\\
=&\frac{\theta}2-\frac12\cos^2(t)+\frac14\sin(\theta)\bigg|_{\arctan 2}^{\arctan 4}\\
=&-\frac1{85}+\frac12(\arctan4-\arctan2).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_2^4 \frac{1+x}{1+2 x^2+x^4} d x = & \int_2^4 \frac{1+x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_2^4\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) d\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)\right]_2^4+\frac{1}{2} \int_2^4 \frac{1}{x^2+1} d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{85}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\tan ^{-1} 4-\tan ^{-1} 2\right)
\end{aligned}
$$